# Is it possible for two single photons with phase coherence between them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

Is it possible for two single photons with phase coherence between them?

Of course, according to the uncertain principle, the phase of a single photon is undefined.

But is it possible to generate a bi-photon source, which contains a single photon $|1_p\rangle$ and the other single photon $|1_s\rangle$ always with a constant phase difference, i.e. $\phi_p-\phi_s=$constant? (And of course, $\phi_p$ and $\phi_s$ are in general unknown.)

Comment: Could you clarify the conditions and context of this question?

Answer (score 1):

As flippiefanus says , if you are talking of phases in the quantum mechanical wavefunctions describing the individual photons, there is not much sense, because any measurable quantity from the quantum wave functions needs an *accumulation of measurements* in order to display the probability distributions, which are the only predictions of quantum mechanical wavefunctions.

The phase/correlation of spins  between two photons can have a meaning though.

It happens naturally: take the [pi0 to two gamma photons.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion#Neutral_pion_decays)The phase difference between the spins two gamma  in the lab is fixed , once the decay  happens.

Your question then can be considered as a special case of [entanglement.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement)

Comment: Entangled states are superposed by two product states, while the meaning of the relative phase is still not "the relative phase between two photons". But indeed, the entangled state has the phase correlation between two product states. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The relative phase between two photons makes no sense. Consider the two expressions
$$ |\phi_1\rangle = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1_a\rangle + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\exp(i\phi)|1_b\rangle $$
and
$$ |\phi_2\rangle = |1_a\rangle|1_b\rangle . $$
The first state where we have a superposition with a relative phase produces a single photon state. The second one produces a two photon state, but there is no relative phase.

Comment: thanks for this, I corrected my answer.

Comment: Ya, the first state is even not a quantum mechanical language because it's not normalized. The second one is a product state which is no relative phase. Thanks.

Comment: I added the normalization. It does not affect the explanation. The get a two photon state, you need to form products.

Comment: It's actually a single-photon state with two modes, a and b, not a two-photon state. Strictly speaking, it should be written in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[|1_a0_b\rangle +|0_a1_b\rangle]$. Hence, it seems no formula to express "two single photons with phase coherence".

Comment: There is only one vacuum, which does not carry any quantum numbers. That is, unless your "modes" represent different physical system in which you can distinguish different vacua.

Comment: The vacuum actually contains infinite modes. Different modes can be different frequencies, polarizations, etc. Even the expression $1/\sqrt(2)(|1_a\rangle +|1_b\rangle)$ means a single photon in a superposition of two different modes a and b, with each probability of 1/2. The related experiment is here, https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7790.

Comment: The interpretation of the manuscript you are referring to is controversial. It tries to proof spooky action at a distance. Therefore, it can't serve as support for your claim. The vacuum does not contain any degrees of freedom because it does not contain anything that can carry those degrees of freedom. By making this claim you get nonsensical situations such as that the vacuum is orthogonal to itself.

Comment: There is no problem with a single photon being a superposition of two different modes. This is allowed because the basis in terms of which such states are represented is not unique. There are infinitely many such bases all related by unitary transformations.